# Abstract Data Types vs. Parametric Polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, abstract, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to get a grip on the relationship between these two concepts.

First consider an example of an **Abstract Data Type**:

```
data Tree a = Nil 
            | Node { left  :: Tree a,
                     value :: a,
                     right :: Tree a }
```

According to Haskell wiki:

> This type is abstract because it leaves some aspects of its structure undefined, to be provided by the user of the data type. This is a weak form of abstract data type. [Source](https://wiki.haskell.org/Abstract_data_type)

Now consider the notion of **parametric polymorphism**:

> **Parametric polymorphism** refers to when the type of a value contains one or more (unconstrained) type variables, so that the value may adopt any type that results from substituting those variables with concrete types. -- [Source](https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism#Parametric_polymorphism)

Here an example of `id :: a -> a` is given:

> For example, the function `id :: a -> a` contains an unconstrained type variable a in its type

**Question:** What is the formal relationship between these two concepts? In particular, are all instances of **abstract data types** also instances of **parametric polymorphism**? What about vice versa?

Comment: As a warning, this is *not* what people typically mean by the term "abstract data type" as even the referenced page goes on to say.  In fact, I find it bizarre that someone decided to use the term that way. As given in that wiki page, a parameterized data type does require parametric polymorphism (of some sort at least), and such a type is simply an example of a parameterized type.  The usual meaning of "abstract data type" does have intimate connections to parametric polymorphism though.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to realize. First, your example `Tree` is actually a **parametric type**, which is a special kind of abstract type. Second, **parametric polymorphisms can be types or functions**. With both of these things in mind, it is obvious that neither abstract types nor parametric polymorphisms are supersets of the other. However, any parametric polymorphism **which is a type** is also an abstract type. In otherwords, abstract types *are* a superset of **parametrically polymorphic types** (dunno if they're actually called that).

Answer (score -2):

The reason `Tree` is an abstract data type because it doesn't specify any of the details about *how* you implement it. How do you add a value to the tree? How do you remove a value? The type only defines the *structure* of the tree: it is either empty or a node that store a value of type `a` and references to two other trees.

Parametric polymorphism doesn't have anything to do with either the structure or the dynamics of the type. Instead, it refers to the fact that you have actually defined a *family* of related types. Whether you have a `Tree Int`, or a `Tree Char`, or a `Tree (StateT (Int, Char) (MaybeT Float IO ()))`, the implementation will remain the same.